# Persist data into BLOB / CLOB datatype in Oracle DB using Apache Camel Framework

Tags: java, oracle, apache-camel, blob, clob

Need to store data (XML) to **BLOB datatype** in oracle DB using **Apache Camel** framework. 
Executing normal queries were fine. But when I tried to persist data into BLOB, the oracle DB wanted a compatible type.
I tried using **utl_raw.cast_to_raw** while trying to convert raw data into BLOB compatible type.

This works fine for smaller data but when data is huge like a large request XML with **more than 2048 characters** are there, error **SQL Error: ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: raw variable length too long** is thrown.

Can someone please help let me know how data more than 2048 characters could be stored in a BLOB datatype using Apache Camel ?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: It would help if you could mention which camel component you use to call the database (camel-sql, camel-jdbc, etc.) and show an example of the code you tried which led to the error.

Comment: It is Camel - SqlComponent.
//

<bean id="sql" class="org.apache.camel.component.sql.SqlComponent">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
 </bean>

Comment: As you have not yet posted any code. Maybe this SO answer helps to find the right solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34530594/how-to-insert-blob-using-camel-sql-component-with-oracle-database#34617215

Comment: Thanks ! This was helpful

Comment: I posted an answer with the obvious examples which should work, but it's hard to know if it's the correct answer without an actual code example of what didn't work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an exemple that works fine when tested with HSQLDB (I don't have an Oracle database handy to test, but it should work the same):

```
// This is just to have some relatively large ammount of data to insert in the BLOB, details don't matter
private static final byte[] LARGE_DATA.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
static {
    final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(10000);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4000; i++) {
        builder.append('a');
    }
    LARGE_STRING = builder.toString();
}

from("direct:clobTest")
.process(new Processor() {
    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        exchange.getIn().setHeader("myParam", LARGE_DATA);
    }
})
.to("sql:INSERT INTO clob_table(clob_col) VALUES(:#myParam)");
```

Alternatively, it also works with an input stream instead of a byte array:

```
final InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(LARGE_DATA);
exchange.getIn().setHeader("myParam", is);
```

Comment: THANKS !! This was much helpful.

Just storing the STRING VALUE TO BYTE ARRAY as bytes and passing this byte array reference to the insert query allowed storing as blob content

Comment: You're welcome! Please consider marking the answer as "accepted" if it does correctly answer your question.

Comment: Where did LARGE_DATA come from?

Comment: How would this be done with an OUT variable in the sql call?