# Camel calls stored procedure which works fine, except for new mystery ORA exception

Tags: java, spring, oracle, apache-camel

I have a major problem with Camel/Spring framework/Oracle. My middleware calls many stored procedures, but one has a problem. Code looks like:

```
.to("sql-stored:someschema.somepackagename.someprocedure(" + 
    "OUT VARCHAR op_pending_list, OUT INTEGER op_return_status, OUT VARCHAR op_return_message)?dataSource=#somedatasource")
```

This is a nightly job that ran fine for 3 weeks, but now fails every night.

That procedure logs (to a db table) that everything is fine. The very last thing it does is log the result count and status code and that indicates working as expected.

On processing the response, middleware detects and logs the Oracle exception:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException CallableStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [{call someschmea.somepackagename.someprocedure(?, ?, ?)}]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

Possibly the return value (Integer) might need to change to Number (NUMERIC in Camel). Integer is used in a number of other places without issue.

Another possibility is the return content is too large, I think it is around 75K. Declared as VARCHAR in middleware. In the stored procedure it is CLOB, but there is no Java type for that. Correction: there is a Java type for CLOB, but no idea how to use it. If I use CLOB it blows up trying to make the call.

Another possibility is that it is after logging (in the stored procedure) the exception occurs, even though the write to the table works and there isn’t any code left to run.

Possible spring framework problem?

We have 3 environments, works fine in DEV and TEST, fails in PROD. Used to work in PROD for a while....

thoughts?

Comment: Java has an SQL [CLOB](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Types.html#CLOB) type... How are the Java variables that are bound to the OUT parameters defined?

Comment: As the procedure fails every night for last 3 weeks, *something* changed. Might be that content size was much smaller before, as now - as you said - it is 75K. It shouldn't be too difficult to verify it: modify the procedure and put e.g. "Gerry" into the return content - that *should* fit. Doesn't matter that it isn't what you'd expect as the result, but - you don't have it for 3 weeks now, so one more night won't make a difference. If the procedure finishes OK, then you got it. I don't know Java so - have a look at what Alex said.

Comment: Maybe this is how to do it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39466517/persist-data-into-blob-clob-datatype-in-oracle-db-using-apache-camel-framework Sure would be nice if the Camel people would document this stuff, or if they have, if I could find it.

Comment: And somebody does it in XML, but how to do in Java https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72237216/retrieve-clob-data-using-apache-camel

Comment: Wrote a test stored procedure and found 32K is okay, 75K blows up. Changing the stored procedure to implement paging. Still no CLOB, no idea at all what that would look like.